# Sort array from particular index to an particular index

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Guys.
How to sort an array from particular index to a particular index, not full array sort. I am searching a lot but not find any solution so please tell me how to do this.

Comment: It would be better if you could also share your code to show what you have tried, or to know where you went wrong.

Comment: What have you tried so far? One solution comes to mind, however probably not the most efficient, which is slicing the array first into smaller arrays, based on your indices. Then sort the part you want to have sorted and combine the arrays again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is extract that specific range from array sort it and after that replace that specific range with sorted array.

**Ex**

```
var array = [1,50,42,15,3,25,63,7,26,8,10,36,78,12]
let sliceSortedArray = array[5...10].sorted()
array.removeSubrange(5...10)
array.insert(contentsOf: sliceSortedArray, at: 5)
print(sliceSortedArray) // [7, 8, 10, 25, 26, 63]
print(array) // [1, 50, 42, 15, 3, 7, 8, 10, 25, 26, 63, 36, 78, 12]
```

**Edit** As @Martin R suggested you can also use [`replaceSubrange(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2853120-replacesubrange).

```
array.replaceSubrange(5...10, with: array[5...10].sorted())
```

Comment: Slightly simpler: `array.replaceSubrange(5...10, with: array[5...10].sorted())
`

Comment: @MartinR Can you still use `array[range] = otherarray`?  That would simplify it even further.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for good suggestion, edited answer with `replaceSubrange`.

Comment: @DavidBerry: `array[range] = ArraySlice(array[range].sorted())` would work, but there is an even simpler solution, see below.

Answer (score 5):

You can call `sort()` directly on a slice of the array:

```
var array = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
array[2...7].sort()

print(array)
// [9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `filter` and `sort` which will return a new array with sorted elements. Something along the lines of

```
let newArray = originalArray.filter {
    //This is where you filter based on indexes
}.sort {
    //This is where you sort your filtered array
}
```